# How to reliably reference WindowsBase assembly from C++/CLI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, .net-6.0

My .NET 6.0 based C++/CLI projects uses WindowsBase with the following in the project file

```
<Reference Include="WindowsBase">
  <HintPath>$(NetCoreTargetingPackRoot)\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\6.0.0\ref\net6.0\WindowsBase.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Today, my build started failing (couldn't find "WindowsBase" anymore) because the folder I reference was no longer there

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\6.0.0
```

Instead all I see is

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\6.0.2
```

It's great that Microsoft updated me but I am not sure now how to update my build.  My co-worker does not have this subfolder.  She has 6.0.0 still.  Even after running windows update.  So I cannot just go into my project file and change the `6.0.0` to `6.0.2` or her machine won't be able to build.

I don't understand how this got deleted out from under me. Does Visual Studio take care of this?  Windows? I did not deliberately uninstall it.  Not sure what the best approach to take is.

Is there some sort of "currently installed version" macro I can use?  Do I try to go manually install 6.0.0 again?  Perhaps I should reference a different folder altogether (e.g. `dotnet/shared`)?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1 if that matters.

Comment: What happens if you remove `HintPath` altogether?

Comment: It doesn't find the assembly at all

Comment: The .net version is not upgraded by Windows update (typically), but by either manually installing the new runtime or upgrading VS. So make sure your coworker has the same VS version and/or manually install the latest service pack SDK from https://aka.ms/dotnet-download